# Button crashes on second click, removeView() exception

Tags: java, android, logcat

When I click the calculate button for the first time it works fine but on the second click after the Result Dialog has been dismissed the app crashes.`logcat` shows the error  The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView on the child's parent first.` What should I do now? and how do I add the removeView?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    float Remaining,Departure,TotUplift,SG,DiscResult;
    int CalUpliftResult;

    TextView RemainingTV,DepartureTV,UpliftTV,SGtv,CalcUpliftTV,DiscrepancyTV,resultOne,resultTwo;
    EditText RemainingET,DepartureET,TotUpliftET,SGet,CalcUpliftET,DiscrepancyET;
    Button calculateButton,okButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupView();

         final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);        
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
        resultOne=(TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.resultOne); //resultone is a textview in xml dialog
        resultTwo=(TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.resultTwo);
        alert.setTitle("RESULT");
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.setView(textEntryView);


        alert.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });








        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                if(validationET())
                {


                getETvalue();
                evaluation();
                CalcUpliftTV.setText(String.valueOf(CalUpliftResult));
                DiscrepancyTV.setText(String.valueOf(DiscResult));
                resultOne.setText("Calc. Uplift (KG)= "+String.valueOf(CalUpliftResult));
                resultTwo.setText("Discrepancy(%)= "+String.valueOf(DiscResult));
                    alert.show();




                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please give all inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });




    }
```

Comment: please add complete code. This occurs when viewGroup is already present and is re-added in the same activity. Try removerAllViews() at dialog dismiss. This will solve the problem.

Comment: code is probably missing the hints about the bug. BTW , you don't have to call dismiss on a button of the alertDialog- you can even set null as its listener .

Comment: So the alert dialog automatically dismisses on any of its button's onClicks? And I'm not able to use removeAllViews (), can you write the correction and repost the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the alertdialog must be created inside the onclick of the calculate button, so that each time I click it, the dialog gets created all over again thus preventing interference from previous dialog values. here's the corrected code segment:

```
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


        if(validationET())
        {

             final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);        
                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
            resultOne=(TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.resultOne); //resultone is a textview in xml dialog
            resultTwo=(TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.resultTwo);
            alert.setTitle("RESULT");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alert.setView(textEntryView);


            alert.setNeutralButton("OK",null);




        getETvalue();
        evaluation();
        CalcUpliftTV.setText(String.valueOf(CalUpliftResult));
        DiscrepancyTV.setText(String.valueOf(DiscResult));
        resultOne.setText("Calc. Uplift (KG)= "+String.valueOf(CalUpliftResult));
        resultTwo.setText("Discrepancy(%)= "+String.valueOf(DiscResult));
        AlertDialog alertD = alert.create();
        alertD.show();






        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please give all inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


});
```